# Flagging "expected output" comments as "no longer needed"

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Often I have seen questions with the following (or similar) comments:

> What is your expected output

and

> I updated my question with the expected output

Is it appropriate to flag both comments as "no longer needed"? Frequently the "What is your expected output" comment has several upvotes.

My expectation is that it is OK to do so, because neither comment adds any value any more. This was more a question of making sure before I started flagging...

Comment: Yes. Any comment requesting clarification that has since been edited into the question can be flagged. There's no reason to let a comment section be 10+ comments long when over half of those have been addressed.

Comment: As a answer-er in mod-rewrite and regex related questions we need to ask the expected output to the user to test the cases. but still after the op got what is best for them the comment kind of do nothing.

Comment: why not make a flag `please delete` that sends a message to the poster of the comment ?

Comment: @Chris_Rands I updated my question with the expected output

Comment: more work for the mods... people should delete those comments themselves first...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre absolutely. But how often does that happen?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since the expected output has been edited in into the question, what are those comments needed for?

These are the poster examples of *"no longer needed"* comments: They *were* needed once. But not any more.

The [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) currently says (although is not completely up to date since it's missing the new *unkind* flags) :

> no longer needed — the comment is obsolete, chatty, or otherwise unnecessary

But it used to say, regarding this type of flag:

> obsolete — a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been addressed by an edit to the post, clarified by additional comments, or contains no context because it references deleted content

The old wording fully explains the scenario you are describing.

Comment score is not relevant. These comments do not bring any value any more, and preserving the conversation is not useful for future readers, and might even be distracting, since the eye will certainly be drawn to high scoring comments. Thus, they are the very definition of **noise**.

Although NLN is nominally the perfect flag for these cases, sometimes the edits are not immediately obvious and can be missed by a mod reviewing your flag. In some of these cases, raising a custom flag drawing attention to the edit that incorporated the comment's content can be practical (to avoid missteps).

Flag away, your flags will almost certainly be honoured (barring occasional human error).

Comment: Out of curiosity, would this also apply to "Updated question for readability" comments? I see these all over the place and they seem like noise to me.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley Exactly the same criteria applies. What value do these comments provide? Are they _needed_ for future visitors? I think not.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @yivi thanks for adding the old wording to your answer. Under that definition such comments are definitely "no longer needed".

Comment: Just to emphasise with yivi says here: not only is it appropriate to flag these kind of comments as "no longer needed", they are *perfect* examples of what the flag is *for*. Its description leads with "obsolete" as a reason that a comment might be NLN, and the comments in the question are textbook examples of what obsolete comments look like. It would be hard to make up a scenario where a NLN flag was more obviously and uncontroversially justified than the one given here.

Answer (score 4):

To address the question and some comments:

> why not make a flag please delete that sends a message to the poster of the comment ?

and

> more work for the mods... people should delete those comments themselves first..

People browsing questions and asking for improvements will often not go back to those posts. It's unreasonable to expect people to keep track of changes to all the posts they browse.

Feel free to flag any comments asking for clarification in a question when edits addressing those comments are made. Use the "No Longer Needed" flag.

Mods are ok deleting these comments. It doesn't take long.

The "no Longer Needed" flag is the quickest to process. Custom flags take longer. The Unkind flags take the longest, as they often involve a judgement call and review of the comment thread to get a feel for the comment within context.